# how to set up multiple IP addresses on my linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I'm doing some computer network homework and I'm supposed to develop some sort of Peer to Peer file sharing software, and when I wanna test it I need to run a few (5) instances on my linux/ubuntnu 11.10 . which means each one need to has a unique IP address. I heard I can do that but I dunno how. how can I have many IP addresses on a single computer? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not really clear what you are trying to do, but you can run multiple virtual machines (virtualization) on your PC to do your tests using a single machine.

If you want to have multiple IP addresses on the same physical interface, that is another thing. If this is what you want, you can do it the old way using `ifconfig` or the new way using `ip addr add`.

The old way:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0:0 your.ip.addr.ess netmask your.sub.net.mask up
```

The new way:

```
$ sudo ip addr add your.ip.addr.ess/mask.bits dev eth0
```

Of course, you need to replace `your.ip.addr.ess` with real value like `192.168.1.1` and `your.sub.net.mask` with something like `255.255.255.0`. The `mask.bits` can be something like 24. You may need also to change the device name `eth0`. To view the IPs currently added, you can use `ifconfig` (old) or `ip addr show` (new).

Comment: yes I want  multiple IP addresses on the same physical interface

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a sub-interface in order to assign multiple IPs to the same interface (for e.g. `eth0`).
  The command for assigning e.g. 2 IP addresses like, say, `10.100.10.1/24` and `10.100.10.2/24` to interface `eth0` would be as follows:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 10.100.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

$ sudo ifconfig eth0:1  10.100.10.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

After this restart the network:

```
$ sudo service network restart
```

I hope this answers your question...

Comment: subinterfaces are obsolete since even before kernel 3.0. The recommended way is to use iproute2.